# How to change background color in the Notepad++ text editor?

Tags: themes, editor, notepad++

Does anyone know how to change the background color, font size, and other appearance-based settings in Notepad++? The default is white but I am trying to change it into a dark gray or something else.

Comment: answer for new version (8) is recent ; has  less votes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68060428/54506

Answer (score 477, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Style Configurator

Select Theme: Choose whichever you like best (the top two are easiest to read by most people's preference)

Comment: Recent versions require themes to be placed in [NPP-INSTALL-FOLDER]\themes or %APPDATA%\Notepad++\themes. If you use the [NPP-INSTALL-FOLDER] location, and NPP is installed by default to %ProgramFiles%, ensure Notepad++ runs with Administrator privileges to make changes to the theme.

Comment: There are 4 dark themes near the top of the list in 2nd to 5th place and more below. No installation needed for these. v7.9.5

Comment: An update changed the theme folder from the Notepad++ install folder to AppData.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58431500) for more info.

Answer (score 60):

You may need admin access to do it on your system.

1. Create a folder 'themes' in the Notepad++ installation folder i.e. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++`
2. Search or visit pages like http://timtrott.co.uk/notepad-colour-schemes/ to download the favourite theme. It will be an XML file.

   - Note: I prefer Neon any day.
3. Download the themes from the site and drag them to the `themes` folder.

   - Note: I was unable to copy-paste or create new files in 'themes' folder so I used drag and that worked.
4. Follow the steps provided by *@triforceofcourage* to select the new theme in Notepad++ preferences.

Comment: why does no theme support JSON? damn I just want to invert the normal one or something to keep syntax highlighting for ALL languages...

Answer (score 45):

From version v8 released 2021-06-07 Notepad++ has additional `Dark Mode` option.

To enable it go to `Settings` -> `Preferences` -> `Enable dark mode`

[image: dark mode]

Effect:

[image]

Next step:
Go to `Settings` -> `Style Configurator`

Select Theme: Choose whichever you like best (over half of styles here are  dark, but each is different).

**Hint:** click on theme list and use keyboard arrows  and  to switch between themes and test all of them.

[image]

Effect after all steps (Obsydian theme here):

[image]

Answer (score 24):

There seems to have been an update some time in the past 3 years which changes the location of where to place themes in order to get them working.

Previosuly, themes were located in the Notepad++ installation folder.  Now they are located in AppData:

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\themes
```

My answer is an update to [@Amit-IO's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39398952) about manually copying the themes.

1. In Explorer, browse to: `%AppData%\Notepad++`.
2. If a folder called `themes` does not exist, create it.
3. Download your favourite theme from wherever (see Amit-IO's answer for a good list) and save it to `%AppData%\Notepad++\themes`.
4. Restart Notepad++ and then use `Settings -> Style Configurator`.  The new theme(s) will appear in the list.

Comment: plus 1 to your answer for making others life easier

Comment: Not quite right. In the latest version (7.8.4, early 2020), you can place themes in either [NPP-INSTALL-FOLDER]\themes or %APPDATA%\Notepad++\themes. Not sure which is "better"...

Comment: @AlainD %AppData% folder for local user only, Install folder for all users. Not everyone has access to the install folder, therefor you can always use the %Appdata% folder

Answer (score 8):

If anyone wants to enable dark mode, you may follow the below steps

- Open your Notepad++, and select `Settings` on the menu bar, and choose `Style configurator`.
- Select theme `Obsidian` (you can choose other dark themes)
- Click on `Save & Close`

[image]

Comment: how can i add `Obsidian` if it's not there??

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ changed in the past couple of years, and it requires a few extra steps to set up a dark theme.

[The answer by Amit-IO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39398952) is good, but the example theme that is needed has stopped being maintained. The DraculaTheme is active. Just download the XML and put it in a themes folder. You may need Admin access in Windows.

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\themes
```

https://draculatheme.com/notepad-plus-plus

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to add the theme, a workaround is that go to

```
USER/Appdata/LocalRoaming/Notepad++
```

make sure you save whatever the data is there in `stylers.xml` as back up before.

There you will find a `stylers.xml` you can edit that only, with any xml format you need.
(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dracula/notepad-plus-plus/master/Dracula.xml)

Sometimes even after adding the file, notepadd++ doesn't pick up the theme.
To revert back just edit back `stylers.xml` with the backup file.

After restarting it, you can see notepad++ has taken that style as default.

Answer (score 0):

I have just installed the latest version Notepad++ website (currently it is v8.1) which provides an explicit dark mode setting.
Go to `Settings` -> `Preferences...` -> `Dark Mode` -> check the `Enable dark mode` tick box. The editor might need to be restarted to take effect completely.
https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/