# Setting background image in Notepad++ and Atom

Tags: notepad++, atom-editor

How can I set images as background in my favorite editors?

 I know, I can [change the background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147214/how-to-change-background-color-in-the-notepad-text-editor) and set color themes, but I haven't found a way to set an image like a wallpaper in the background.

How can I set a wallpaper background in Atom and/or Notepad++?

Answer (score 2):

**For Atom**, you can actually just set a `background` with LESS in `File > Settings > Themes > "Choose a Theme" >`*`"your stylesheet"`*.

I've used the following code to set a background image:

```css
body,  /* body is only for the snippet */
.pane {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V0fC.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.editor { /* making it a bit transparent */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}
```